# How to bind function calls in vim

Tags: vimrc, command

Suppose I have some extension that allows for calling some function `foo()`. Can I somehow bind the command `:call foo()` to just `:k` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:command {cmd}` to define a user command. Be aware that all user-defined commands must start with an uppercase letter.

```
:command CallFoo :call foo()
```